AWS App Runner health check fails when using outgoing custom VPC
I have an App Runner service that works Ok when using public access networking configuration for incoming and outgoing traffic.
But I need this service to connect to a aws redis instance that is under a VPC. So I change the App Runner service networking configuration to use a Custom VPC for the outgoing traffic and this is causing the service to fail on start, and hence a roll back of the change happens.
Please See Pic Logs
The VPC Connector that I'm trying to set on the App Runner service basically connects to the VPC where the redis instance is.
I even tried creating a fresh new App Runner, but with the same results.
Any idea of what might be happening here? Couldn't find any useful resource on internet.
Thanks in advance
